# Backgroundworker completes when MQMessage is get

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I have this code which is part of my `BackgroundWorkerXMLPutMessages_DoWork` Sub.

```
Try
            PublicMQVariable.MQMessage_Reply = New MQMessage
            PublicMQVariable.MQMessage_Reply.CorrelationId = PublicMQVariable.MQMessage_Request.MessageId
            PublicMQVariable.MQMessage_Reply.MessageType = MQC.MQMT_REPLY
            PublicMQVariable.MQGetMessageOptions_Reply = New MQGetMessageOptions
            PublicMQVariable.MQGetMessageOptions_Reply.Options = MQC.MQGMO_WAIT + MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING
            PublicMQVariable.MQGetMessageOptions_Reply.MatchOptions = MQC.MQMO_MATCH_CORREL_ID
            PublicMQVariable.MQGetMessageOptions_Reply.WaitInterval = My.Settings.MQ_ReplyTimeOut
            PublicMQVariable.MyStopwatch = New Stopwatch
            PublicMQVariable.MyStopwatch.Start()
            PublicMQVariable.MQQueue_Response.Get(PublicMQVariable.MQMessage_Reply, PublicMQVariable.MQGetMessageOptions_Reply)
            PublicMQVariable.MyStopwatch.Stop()
            PublicMQVariable.MyReplyMessage = PublicMQVariable.MQMessage_Reply.ReadString(PublicMQVariable.MQMessage_Reply.MessageLength)
        Catch ex As MQException
            MsgBox("MQException: compCode: " & ex.CompCode.ToString() & " Reason: " + ex.Reason.ToString() & " - " & ex.Message)
            MQDisconnectAndClose()
            Return
        End Try
```

The moment this code (`PublicMQVariable.MQQueue_Response.Get(PublicMQVariable.MQMessage_Reply, PublicMQVariable.MQGetMessageOptions_Reply)`) is executed it returns to `BackgroundWorkerXMLPutMessages_RunWorkerCompleted` without finishing the rest of the code above.

Why does this happen and what can I do to prevent this "premature completion"?

Answer (score 2):

It failed with an exception.  Forgetting to check e.Error in the RunWorkerCompleted event handler is a very common mistake.  Easier to debug if you use Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown checkbox for CLR exceptions.

Comment: Hans, where can I find this checkbox?

Comment: Look at the menu at the top of the Visual Studio window, locate Debug to the right of Build.  Open the menu and locate Exceptions.   A dialog opens, you see the Thrown checkboxes.